# Is there a way to render a dynamically created component next to its sibling

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to render dynamically created component next to its sibling.

I tried using

```
const onEnter = (e) => {
  ...
  ReactDOM.render(<Breakdown message={message} />, e.currentTarget);
}
```

But ReactDOM.render clears its children components and replaces it with my new component.

Is there like a jquery $(e.currentTarget).append() function in React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const onEnter = (e) => {
  ...
  const elem = document.createElement("DIV");
  e.currentTarget.appendChild(elem);
  ReactDOM.render(<Breakdown message={message} />, elem);
}
```

However, it is up to you refining the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would want to use state to manage showing/hiding a component. First import the `useState` hook like so

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
```

Then you can use a boolean state to keep track of whether or not you should show Breakdown

```
const [showBreakdown, setShowBreakdown] = useState(false)

const onEnter = (e) => {
  setShowBreakdown(false)
}

...

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    ...
    <SomeComponent>
    <Breakdown message={message} />
  </React.Fragment>
);
```